# How to setup size of selection box?

Tags: inkscape

If I clip object by rectangle, it looks like this:

[image]

Selection box is bigger than rectangle, it's like full object without clip

But earlier (in 0.91), selection box coped size of clip:

[image]

How can I setup this functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>)
2. Go to Tools
3. And find the "**Bounding box to use**" setting

Set the radio button from "**Geometric bounding box**" to "**Visual bounding box**".

[image: Preferences screen of Inkscape]

Comment: Good to know. But now strokes are also included in the bounding box. Is there a way to keep the geometric bounding box in terms of strokes, but the visiual bounding box in terms of clipping?

Comment: Not that I know of, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

other solution didnt work for me could not find bounding box to use anyplace.
did this instead
selected image
then
Edit/Resize page to selection
[image: e]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.